# Custom default gravatar in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have done this so many times but for some reason it doesn't work today!

This is the function used for adding a default gravatar:

```
//***Custom Gravatar**/
add_filter( 'avatar_defaults', 'custom_gravatar' );  
function custom_gravatar ($avatar_defaults) {
     $myavatar = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/gravatar.png';
     print_r($myavatar);
     $avatar_defaults[$myavatar] = "Custom Gravatar";
     return $avatar_defaults;
}
```

In Settings > Discussion, the title "Custom Gravatar" shows, but no image. No image on the front-end either.

`print_r($myavatar);` shows the correct URL.

The URL shows the correct image.

The image src on the front-end outputs like this:

`http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/0d2ef201aafaf4849d2fd2bccaba6ea4?s=60&d=http%3A%2F%2Fstaging.cashmoneylife.com%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2Fgenesis-sample-master%2Fimages%2Fgravatar.png&r=g`

Am I overlooking something really simple?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26055711/show-custom-default-avatar-instead-of-gravatar) which states (quoting the [Gravatar documents](https://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/)):

> When you include a default image, Gravatar will automatically serve up
>   that image if there is no image associated with the requested email
>   hash. There are a few conditions which must be met for default image
>   URL:
>
> - **MUST be publicly available** (e.g. cannot be on an intranet, on a local    development machine, behind HTTP Auth or some other firewall
>     etc).    Default images are passed through a security scan to avoid
>     malicious    content.
> - MUST be accessible via HTTP or HTTPS on the standard ports,    80 and 443, respectively.
> - MUST have a recognizable image extension    (jpg, jpeg, gif, png)
> - MUST NOT include a querystring (if it does, it    will be ignored)

Any chance you are developing locally???

Comment: Thanks Daniel - it meets all of those criteria - I'm not developing locally. I tried `urldecode` on the string but it didn't help

Comment: Any chance you can show what the `print_r($myavatar);` is showing?

Comment: In the backend this `http://staging.cashmoneylife.com/wp-content/themes/genesis-sample-master/images/gravatar.png` but in the front end the img src is `http://0.gravatar.com/avatar/0d2ef201aafaf4849d2fd2bccaba6ea4?s=60&d=http%3A%2F%2Fstaging.cashmoneylife.com%2Fwp-content%2Fthemes%2Fgenesis-sample-master%2Fimages%2Fgravatar.png&r=g`

Comment: http://staging.cashmoneylife.com is password protected.  Basically your staging site is behind HTTP Auth... so you have actually failed the first bullet in my list.  Remove the HTTP Auth and see if it works.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I had completely overlooked the protected directory - it is working now